How to implement TURN (Traversal Using Relays around NAT)?
I am writing a VoIP server using UDP sockets which I want to run on a VPS with public IP. Apparently, sending UDP packets from server to client behind NAT is problematic, since most NATs assign random ports to the device for each outgoing connection. TURN server should supposedly solve the issue, but I don't understand how and can't find a lot of relevant information on that. I've looked through some implementations (WebRTC, Coturn) but they are too huge and incomprehensible. My questions are:

Can TURN-like behavior combined with regular server operation?
How does having relay server help in delivering UDP packets between 2 clients if their addresses(ports) always change? Reading through RFC8656 didn't really help with understanding how client's port numbers are updated.
are there other ways around NATs?

Edit: When posting the question, I didn't understand some things which I have explained in the answer

We have no idea what you are capable of implementing.  But in any case, this question is...premature.  SO can help with specific, focused issues you're having with your code; it's not the place for design advice, or "how do i implement ?".

What I did not understand was how relay server could keep UDP connection with a client if it's address changes, but now that I've been running tests for half a day, I kind of get the Idea, I'll post it as a reply

I figured it out 
I somehow got the idea that server can NOT reply with udp packet to a client through NAT; in which I was wrong, it definitely can, It only should be the same socket through which client communicated in the first place (I think that each bound socket maps to unique port on NAT)
You can avoid STUN servers because (at least linux) socket API literally has a way to get source ip/port (function recvfrom), and if you send some data back to that socket in a reasonable amount of time (if it's still opened), the server will reach the client
I got the wrong idea because everyone was making such a big fuss about NAT traversal that I thought there's some special magic behind it, while really it's almost as simple as doing things on localhost.
